# How to do parallel HTTP requests in Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I'm building a Ruby on Rails app that access about 6-7 APIs, grabs information from them based on user's input, compares and display results to the users (the information is not saved in the database). I will be using Heroku to deploy the app. I would like those HTTP requests to access the APIs to be done in parallel so the answer time is better instead of doing it sequential. What do you think is the best way to achieve this in Heroku?

Thank you very much for any suggestions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to actually do the requests on the server side (tfe's javascript solution is a good idea), your best bet would be using [EventMachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine). Using EventMachine gives a simple way to do non-blocking IO.

Also check out [EM-Synchrony](https://github.com/igrigorik/em-synchrony) for a set of Ruby 1.9 fiber aware clients (including HTTP).

All you need to do for a non-blocking HTTP request is something like:

```
require "em-synchrony"
require "em-synchrony/em-http"
EM.synchrony do
    concurrency = 2
    urls = ['http://url.1.com', 'http://url2.com']

    # iterator will execute async blocks until completion, .each, .inject also work!
    results = EM::Synchrony::Iterator.new(urls, concurrency).map do |url, iter|

        # fire async requests, on completion advance the iterator
        http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(url).aget
        http.callback { iter.return(http) }
        http.errback { iter.return(http) }
    end

    p results # all completed requests
    EventMachine.stop
end
```

Goodluck!

Answer (score 1):

You could always make the requests client-side using Javascript. Then not only can you run them in parallel, but you won't even need the round-trip to your own server.

Comment: We can only skip the round trip if we don't need some sort of API key, correct? Otherwise we need to go to the server first because we can't store the API key on the client.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried parallelizing requests like that. But I've tried parallel on heroku, works like a charm! This is my simple blog post about it.

http://olemortenamundsen.wordpress.com/2010/10/17/spawning-multiple-threads-at-heroku-using-parallel/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at creating each request as a background job:
http://blog.heroku.com/archives/2009/7/15/background_jobs_with_dj_on_heroku/

The more 'Workers' you buy from Heroku, the more background jobs can be processed concurrently, leaving your 'Dynos' to serve your users.

Comment: The problem with doing it as a background job is that dj saves the pending jobs in the database, so, the processes are added to the queue, then user has to wait until one of the workers query the database to see what job is waiting and then it is executed. So in addition to the waiting time to query the APIs, i'm adding waiting time until the workers start the job. That's why i think this is not the best option.. but i could be wrong.

Comment: As an alternative, you could use typhoeus (https://github.com/pauldix/typhoeus) to run the requests in parallel.