# Local EventMachine without opening port

Tags: ruby, http, asynchronous, macruby

I don't know a lot about TCP/IP but I am a self taught web developer. I have worked with EventMachine a little bit, Node.js a little bit, and recently wrote my first Mac application using MacRuby. I had an idea for a new Mac app that involved making a bunch of HTTP requests asynchronously like EventMachine and Node allow you to do. However, I don't mean for this to be a web server, so I don't need to open a port or accept requests from the outside world. I only need to handle HTTP requests in a non-blocking manner in a MacRuby application. There may be a better way to handle this, but this is an idea I just thought of and didn't know how I would implement.

Answer (score 0):

[Using EventMachine works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088849/how-to-do-parallel-http-requests-in-heroku), but you might also try [Typhoeus](https://github.com/typhoeus/typhoeus), which is specifically geared towards this.